# Dual Passports, Different names-Singapore

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, singapore

Due to covid restrictions, I had to book my tickets this way.  I am flying from the US to Singapore on my US passport with my married name.  I am staying in Singapore for 4 days (entering SIngapore on my US passport.).  I then am flying from SIngapore to Perth on my Australian passport with my maiden name.

Will there be any issues entering SIngapore on one passport with one name and leaving on the other one.

I know generally you are suppose to enter and exit on the same one but does anyone have insight?

Thanks!

Comment: Closely related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel

Comment: Just show your US passport to Singapore Immigration. The reason for your flight booking to Australia with your Australian passport will be clear to them.

Comment: Some countries will indeed have an issue if you try to exit the country and they can’t match you up to an entry record. Not sure if that would be the case in Singapore but I would expect so. They will in that case most certainly ask if you used another passport on entry, which you can then show them. I wonder if the simplest proposition wouldn’t be to just enter with your Australian passport (and again, if that raises an issue, but this seems less likely to me, show the US passport).

Answer (score 1):

Check in for your flight to Australia with your Australian passport.  When you get to the passport control before you board your flight, show your US passport, because that's where your entry stamp is for Singapore, and that's where you need to get an exit stamp.

If, when you check in, the airline asks about your immigration status on Singapore, show them the US passport with the entry stamp.  Similarly, if the passport inspector asks about your ability to enter Australia, show the Australian passport.  Most countries pay no attention to travelers' destinations at the exit control, but a few do.  I don't know about Singapore.  In any event, you're allowed to be a dual citizen, so you can show both passports when it's necessary.

(I'm aware of no reason for you not to use the Australian passport for the trip to Singapore; US dual citizens *can* check in for international flights leaving the US with their non-US passports; I do it all the time and there's never been the slightest hint of a problem.  But if you have a good reason for using the US passport to fly to Singapore, follow the advice above.)

Comment: So when the ticket was booked, I could only book it under my USA passport due to the VTL restrictions. Australia was not approved when I booked the ticket.    I have a covid pass to enter Singapore under my USA passport under my married name.  That is what is making this more difficult than normal.  I just want to make sure Singapore will let me leave!